# Dependency Injection on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

When we are in the need to access another class within a repository , the below technique works as expected.

ie. 
    namespace App;
    class AbcRepo implements AbcInterface {

```
}

namespace App;
class DefRepo implements DefInterface {

    protected $abc;

    public function __construct(AbcInterface $abc) {
      $this->abc = $abc;    
    } 
}
```

So when I register this in the service provider :

```
$app->bind('App\DefInterface', function($app) {
   return new App\DefRepo(App::make('App\AbcInterface'));
});
```

The question that's bothering me is doing this :

```
 new App\DefRepo(App::make('App\AbcInterface'));
```

Is it the correct approach. We (i mean I) never unit test a service provide , so I could simply ignore as this works. But any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, however it is better to let typehinted dependency injection initialize `RefRepo`.

```
$app->bind('App\DefInterface', 'App\DefRepo');
$app->bind('App\AbcInterface', 'App\AbcRepo');
```

That means Laravel will try to initialize `DefRepo` when a class that implements `DefInterface` is needed. Because `DefRepo` needs `AbcInterface` the class `AbcRepo` will be injected into the instance.

Comment: So basically using the closure when binding , is optional.

Comment: Yes. If you pass a string it will use that as class name